# How can I make hidden field is safe?

Tags: php, html, security, hidden-field

I use `<input type="hidden" />`  to pass some value so I want to make the hidden field is safe I have a user profile page I get username of member by this

```
$userprofilename = $_GET['username'];
```

when some body post any thing to user I get username of profile by

```
<input type="hidden" name="userprofile" value="<? echo $userprofilename; ?>" />
```

but in google chrome any body can change userprofile value, how can I make it safe?

thanks

Comment: you can create a session on the form page and retrieve it on the submit page then destroy it after user

Comment: Not just in Chrome, almost in any browser you can change code. It's not advised to do that. Use session instead.

Answer (score 3):

Then instead of storing it in a public form, store it inside a server session

Instead of

```
$userprofilename = $_GET['username'];
```

Do

```
 session_start();
 $userprofilename = $_SESSION['username'];
```

And when they login, add their value to the session

```
 // on login
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username']=$userprofilename;
```

Comment: Then you can probably fetch it from database using any of the identifying fields available to you. Your current code and question visible to us do not provide enough information for that case

Comment: i  use `rel=""` to pass value to insert page like this

**Html** code

    <p>post 1</p> 
    <a href="" rel="<? echo $id_post; ?>">Like</a>
    <br />
    <p>post 2</p> 
    <a href="" rel="<? echo $id_post; ?>">Like</a>
    <br />
    <p>post 3</p> 
    <a href="" rel="<? echo $id_post; ?>">Like</a>
how can i safe rel

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to not pass the client at all but keep it on the server-side. This is what [sessions](http://php.net/book.session) are for: store the value in the server-side session then you can retrieve it on form submission.

However, if you don’t want to use sessions, you can at least detect whether the hidden values got tampered by signing the hidden values using a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) like [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/hash_hmac). Here’s a simple example:

```
function create_hmac($key, $uri, array $params)
    return hash_hmac('sha256', json_encode(array($uri, $params)), $key);
}
$secret = '7wzvtNgAVCTLPZ27P4L52yzc';

# on form creation
$hidden = array(
    'userprofile' => $_GET['username']
);
$hmac = create_hmac($secret, '/form/submit.php', $hidden);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($hidden)).'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="hmac" value="'.$hmac.'">';

# on form submission
$hidden = json_decode($_POST['hidden'], true);
if ($_POST['hmac'] !== create_hmac($secret, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $hidden)) {
    // invalid HMAC
} else {
    $_POST = $hidden + $_POST;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gumbo, it's not possible to hide javascript code, so anyone can get access to the `create_hmac` function & the secret.

Answer (score 1):

your **form page**

create a session variable like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userprofilename'] = $userprofilename;
```

instead of this hidden

`<input type="hidden" name="userprofile" valu="<? echo $userprofilename; ?>" />`

on your submit page

you can retrieve it as follows

```
    session_start();
    $userprofilename = $_SESSION['userprofilename'];

  // use it as $userprofilename and then unset it
   unset($_SESSION['userprofilename']);
```

**this would be safe because session resides on server and can't be seen by the client. by view html source or firebug etc.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try by encrypting the username and then decrypting it where ever needed, if you don't want to use sessions

Comment: The question relates to the way of passing the data. If you can rephrase your answer, it would be, very close to what the OP wants.